# CSS3D overlapping divs on Mobile Safari

Tags: css, webkit, mobile-safari, wkwebview

Mobile Safari shows the correct version of the UI for a split second.

[image: expectation]

After that the translated 3d surfaces cut into each other.

[image: reality]

```
.top {
background-color: #a58855;
transform: translateY(-50px) rotateX(90deg);
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50px) rotateX(90deg);
}
```

[Please see full code on jsbin](https://jsbin.com/cexoluh/45/edit?html,css,output)

Any ideas how to fix the problem? I tried adding custom z-indexes and z-translations, but nothing seems to help. After half a second image "corrects" itself to the broken state.

Comment: This is a bug that was first reported in 2011. Please see: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=182520